# I'm unable to make databinding changes in catch block inside a coroutine. Why?

Tags: android, kotlin

During my splash activity I'd like my app to ping the server and perform a few quick checks. If this fails, I'd like to display an option to try again, or continue without internet. Here's some basic initialization:

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivitySplashBinding
private val response = MutableLiveData<String>()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    // enable databinding with layout files
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_splash)
    response.value = "Initializing ..."
    response.observe(this, Observer {
        binding.statusText.text = it
    })
    // set up button click listeners here too, omitted for brevity
    checkInternet()

}
```

Setting some TextView values in onCreate works fine, so I know data binding is working.

```
private var job = Job()
private val checkScope = CoroutineScope(job + Dispatchers.IO)

private fun checkInternet() {
    binding.apply {
        buttonTryAgain.visibility = View.GONE
        buttonContinue.visibility = View.GONE
    }
    response.postValue("Checking internet connection...")
    checkScope.async {
        try {
            myApi.retrofitService.getFoo() // this is synchronous
            startNextActivity()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Start exception block")
            response.postValue("Hm, it seems we're unable to reach the server. Check your internet connection?")
            binding.apply {
                buttonTryAgain.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                buttonContinue.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "We never reach here, why?")
        }
    }
}
```

I test by putting the device into airplane mode, and the call to `binding.apply` in the `catch` block never completes. Why? Also, assuming there's a exception here (and async doesn't rethrow exceptions), how can I see it?

Comment: "Start exception block" , do you see this log in your catch block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've been a victim of a [failed lifecycle owner](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/android-data-binding-library-from-observable-fields-to-livedata-in-two-steps-690a384218f2)

> Binding classes have a method called setLifecycleOwner that must be
>   called when observing LiveData from a data binding layout.

Make sure to add the necessary lifecycle owner when working with `Databinding` and `LiveData`

Updated code;

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    // enable databinding with layout files
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_splash)

    binding.lifecycleOwner = this          // this was missing

    response.value = "Initializing ..."
    response.observe(this, Observer {
        binding.statusText.text = it
    })
    // set up button click listeners here too, omitted for brevity
    checkInternet()
```

Edit:

```
private fun checkInternet() {
    binding.apply {
        buttonTryAgain.visibility = View.GONE
        buttonContinue.visibility = View.GONE
    }
    response.postValue("Checking internet connection...")
    checkScope.async {
        try {
            myApi.retrofitService.getFoo() // this is synchronous
            startNextActivity()
        } catch (e: Exception) {

          this@YourActivity.runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable {
            binding.apply {
                buttonTryAgain.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                buttonContinue.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
       })

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that didn't fix it. As per your comment, I do get the "start exception block" log, just not the "we never reach here" one, and only the `buttonTryAgain` Is visible, not the `buttonContinue`. Is there a way to find out what the exception is that is generated inside the catch block when I call `binding.apply{...}`?

Comment: Just check the updated answer, I think we are updating the `View` in the wrong thread.

Comment: OK, that worked, thanks, but 1. why can't I update the UI in the coroutine? 2. This seems so clunky to run a doubly-nested access to the main thread (even after refactoring that work into a utility function). Is this the way it's usually done in android?

Comment: Why? Because your coroutine is set to the IO dispatcher which runs on a separate thread. All Android UI must be updated from the Main (aka UI) thread. You have to run your UI updates on the Main distpatcher or outside a coroutine.

Comment: @Escher you can make use of `withContext(Dispatcher.Main){. //update the ui  }` instead of `runOnUIThread{}` in the catch block.